# Openshift action_hook is not executable

Tags: node.js, openshift, action-hook

I have recently create my first Openshift node application and currently trying to get the build scripts working when I push to the server via git (using **action_hook**).

I am writing the application using PhpStorm on Windows and have had no problem pushing files to the server.

I have create the following file: `.openshift/action_hook/build` which contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
webpack --config $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/webpack.config.js
```

When I push to the server using git, I get the following error:

```
NOTE: The .openshift/action_hooks/build hook is not executable, to make it executable:        
On Windows run:   git update-index --chmod=+x .openshift/action_hooks/build
On Linux/OSX run: chmod +x .openshift/action_hooks/build
```

I have tried the windows command above but when running `git ls-tree HEAD` to check the file permission, I can see they have not changed:

```
100644 blob 1b82131d8b9e9c63b765ef328ecbbfb54f0c70aa    build
```

Has anybody managed to get this working on windows?
Thanks a lot

Comment: It works for me on windows.  However I have to add and commit and push via the git gui.  If I do it thru pycharm it will not work.  I have not taken the time to figure out why.